# relative path using filereader in java

Tags: java, filereader

I am trying to read a file using bufferedReader and Filereader class using relative path, but FileReader() cannot find the specified file.
What path i need to put in FileReader and is there any other method to give relative path. I am attaching code and image of directory.[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvPXG.png)

```
public class FileRead {

    public FileRead(String path) {

        try {
            String currentLine;

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));  // FileNotFoundException
            while(( currentLine=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(currentLine);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FileRead("");
    }

}
```

What changes i need to do, so that i can use FileReader

Comment: If you want a relative path, we need to know what your working directory is. And, the constructor of File does not check if it exists.

Comment: @FrankPuffer, I have attached a image(Directory Structure), you can see directory structure there, And i need to use FileReader, So what path i should put in there.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Please reopen the question as your suggested answer explains about File() and i need to know about FileReader()

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I understood about new File()......i  also need to know about FileReader() path

Comment: Your image shows a part of your directory structure but it says nothing about your working directory.

Comment: @FrankPuffer i m using Eclipse IDE and StringTokenReverse is project folder

Comment: Normally the project folder is the working directory when you are using eclipse. So your class should find the file without specifying your path. Maybe you have set up a different working directory in your run configuration.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. Problem resolved.